# GNUplot: How to make a plot unclosed?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm drawing plots from a file in gnuplot like this:

```
plot "plots.txt" using 1:2 with lines lw 2
```

and I get something like this:

[image: Gnuplot Screenshot]

How can I draw a plot without enclosing it (without the line connecting the leftmost and the rightmost points)? Thank you!

Comment: Hm... It just started working in my other program. And now I hope it won't switch back to how it was. Anyone knows, what is the issue?

Comment: Its your data file, but without seeing it I can't tell you more

Comment: @Cristoph, thank you, I've just found out, what was wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I've just found out what was wrong. It turned out, my file had the data cycled like this:

```
7.4500  18.5567
7.4578  21.5392
7.4656  25.2265
7.4734  29.8230
7.4812  35.5910
7.4890  42.8468
....    ....
7.4500  18.5567
7.4578  21.5392
7.4656  25.2265
7.4734  29.8230
7.4812  35.5910
7.4890  42.8468
....    ....
```